# How to pass a R Shiny reactive expression as a default argument in a custom function

Tags: r, function, shiny, reactive, evaluation

I am trying to pass `input$myInput` text field to a custom function as a predefined argument. This is important to control the functions arguments in future for documentation (roxygen2).

Here is a minimal working example:
The app schould bind the input field to mtcars dataset and apply the custom function `my_DTarguments` with two arguments (1. data, 2. input):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


#function
my_DTarguments <- function(data, input=input$myInput) {
  
  DT::datatable(
    rownames = FALSE,
    data,
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(
      dom = 'frtipB',
      buttons = list(
        list(
          extend = 'csv',
          filename = paste0("mydesiredname-", "cyl-", input, "-", Sys.Date())
        ),
      )
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput(inputId = "myInput", label = "My Input", placeholder = "a"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output) {

  #  combine mtcars with input field 
   mtcars1 <- reactive({ 
     cbind(mtcars, input$myInput)
     })
   
   # apply function to mtcars1 
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    my_DTarguments(mtcars1())
    )
    })    
  }
)
```

The last error after many tries is :  `promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with reactive expressions is that Shiny adds them to the reactive chain and then evaluates all reactive expressions in the chain one by one. We do not know the order in which Shiny does that.

In your case, Shiny tries to evaluate `renderDataTable` and by doing so calls `my_DTarguments()`. However, `myInput` has not been evaluated, yet, hence the error.

When you use a reactive expressions as a *default function argument*, you should always add a in a `req(...)` call (example: `req(input$myInput)`). But you still have to add `input$myInput` in the call to `my_DTarguments()` from `renderDataTable`. But you'll get an empty column, if `input$myInput` is still empty.

Alternatively, you can make sure that `input$myInput` is truthy before calling `my_DTarguments`. In this case, the table will only be shown once `input$myInput` is not empty and Shiny has already evaluated it.

Personally I think the secnond is the cleaner approach. **I recommend that we do not use reactive expressions as default arguments for functions, in general**. Not only does it violate the idea of a default argument when the caller has to add it anyway. The way reactive expressions work they are only available in the runtime environment as needed. A default argument, however, should be available anytime a function is called. That is like adding a predetermined breaking point in our code ... which - of course - we don't want.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


#function
my_DTarguments <- function(data, input=req(input$myInput)) {
  DT::datatable(
    rownames = FALSE,
    data,
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(
      dom = 'frtipB',
      buttons = list(
        #list(
          extend = 'csv',
          filename = paste0("mydesiredname-", "cyl-", input, "-", Sys.Date())
        #),
      )
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput(inputId = "myInput", label = "My Input", placeholder = "a"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #  combine mtcars with input field 
    mtcars1 <- reactive({ 
      cbind(mtcars, input$myInput)
    })
    
    # apply function to mtcars1 
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      my_DTarguments(mtcars1())
      # Alternative approach: call req() here
      # my_DTarguments(mtcars1(), req(input$myInput))
    })
  }
)
```

By the way, there seems to be an issue with the buttons option. I commented 2 lines out, so that the code runs.

Comment: Fantastic @Jan. Sometimes I feel foolish asking such questions, but on the other hand, it is these questions that help me progress and keep me from losing the fun!!!

Comment: Actually, I find the question quite valuable to many learners out there (that is why I changed the title a tiny bit to make it a bit more generic and "findable"). So so don't worry about that. Just ask. :-)

Comment: Could you please check your provided code. Somehow now I can't reproduce the success I already had. I copy your code and get the same error again?

Comment: It works on my system.

Comment: That's strange. Tried on rstudio cloud same code same error. Updated shiny and DT no effect. hmmm?! The really strange thing is that it worked today in the morning. Anyway.

Comment: I mean the input is not passed to the filename: ` filename = paste0("mydesiredname-", "cyl-", input, "-", Sys.Date())`. So the resulting csv filename should include the text in myInput. Many thanks.

Comment: I changed the lines settings the buttons of the data table to `buttons = list(list(extend = 'csv',   filename = paste0("mydesiredname-", "cyl-", input, "-", Sys.Date())))`. That works for me.

Comment: Hurray. You are my hero of the day!